# syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\... on line 161

Tags: php

I get the following error when I open the index page:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on
 line 161
```

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <title>
        <?php
        /*
        * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
        */
        global $page, $paged;

        wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

        // Add the blog name.
        bloginfo( 'name' );

        // Add the blog description for the home / front page.
        $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
        if( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";



        // Add a page number if necessary:
        if( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'bootstrapwp' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

        ?>
    </title>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php
    if( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />



    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.jpg">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">



    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <?php include  'storeclass.php'; ?>
    <style>
        .navbar .nav li a
        {
            padding-right: 0px !important;
        }



    </style>
    <?php
    if( function_exists( 'teboAnalytic' ) ){
        teboAnalytic();
    }
    ?>
</head>
<?php
if($detect->isMobile() AND !$detect->isTablet()){
    ?>
    <style>


        .container
        {
            max-width: 300px;
        }
    </style>
    <body style="background-color: #E7EBF2;padding-top:65px;" <?php body_class(); ?> data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar" data-offset="10">
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    <body style="background-color: #E7EBF2;padding-top:45px;" <?php body_class(); ?> data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar" data-offset="10">
    <?php
} ?>


<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container" style="width:940px;">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="hidden-phone">
                    <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL.'weblogo.png'; ?>" style="width:270px;">
                </li>


                <?php
                if($detect->isMobile() AND !$detect->isTablet()){
                    ?>
                    <li class="dropdown" style="margin-left:15px;">
                    <?php
                }
                else
                {
                    ?>
                    <li class="dropdown offset2">
                    <?php
                } ?>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding:0;">
                    <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>callus.png" style="height:46px;width:203px">
                </a>
                <?php
                if($detect->isMobile() AND !$detect->isTablet()){
                    callUsBanner('mobile');
                }
                else
                {
                    callUsBanner('desktop');
                }
                ?>
                </li><!-- Regular Menu Ends -->



                <li class="divider-vertical">
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
if($detect->isMobile() AND !$detect->isTablet()){
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile-custom.css" />
    <style>
        .hhd
        {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 5px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
} ?>

<div class="container hhd" style="height:41px;">
    <?php
    if($detect->isMobile() AND !$detect->isTablet()){
        ?>

        <img src="weblogo.png" style="width:270px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="styled-select blue semi-square divsel span12">
                <?php menu1(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?
    }  ?>
    <div class="subnavbar navbar navbar hidden-phone">
        <div class="navbar-inner subnav">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar">
                    </span>
                    <span class="icon-bar">
                    </span>
                    <span class="icon-bar">
                    </span>
                </button>
                <ul class="nav" style="font-size:13px;">

                    <li class="hidden-phone">
                        <img src="badge.jpg" style="width:40px;">
                    </li>
                    <li class="hidden-phone">
                        <a href="" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                            <i class="icon-home">
                            </i>Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hidden-phone">
                        <a href="">
                            <i class=" icon-th-large">
                            </i>Store
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hidden-phone">
                        <a href="">
                            <i class=" icon-tag">
                            </i>Bursa
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical subnav">
                    </li>

                    <?php  menuIjo('desktop','top');  ?>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.renav').click(function(e)
        {
            //alert('ha');
            $('section.dropdown-menu *').removeAttr('data-toggle');
        });
</script>
<!-- End Header -->
<!-- Begin Template Content -->
```

could you help me to solve this problem?
thanks

Comment: What is `on line 161` ?

Comment: Make sure open short tags are on. If not, change all `<?` (*should you have more*) to `<?php` where you have `<?  }  ?>` which should be `<?php  }  ?>` that should do it. This looks like WordPress code, so check your plugins too if you are using any.

Comment: Most likely, braces are mismatched. If you systematically remove everything unrelated to the issue unless you end up with a minimal example, you would find the error.

Comment: You probably have error in class <?php include  'storeclass.php'; ?>

Comment: It could be this one: `<?  }  ?> ` on line 132. Try making it `<?php  }  ?> `

Comment: `No syntax errors detected in` this code. Tested with `php -l`

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
   <? with <?php on line number 132 ( <? } ?> to <?php } ?>
```

the correct code will be

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>



<head>
   <title><?php
  /*
   * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
   */
  global $page, $paged;

  wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

  // Add the blog name.
  bloginfo( 'name' );

  // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
  $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
  if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";



// Add a page number if necessary:
  if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'bootstrapwp' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

  ?></title>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />



<!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.jpg">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">



<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
  <?php include  'storeclass.php'; ?>
  <style>
      .navbar .nav li a{
        padding-right: 0px !important;
    }



</style>
  <?php
if ( function_exists( 'teboAnalytic' ) ) {
    teboAnalytic();
}
?>
  </head>
  <?php if ($detect->isMobile() AND !$detect->isTablet()) {?>
  <style>


    .container{
          max-width:300px;
      }
  </style>  
<body style="background-color: #E7EBF2;padding-top:65px;" <?php body_class(); ?> data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar" data-offset="10">    
<?php }else{?>
<body style="background-color: #E7EBF2;padding-top:45px;" <?php body_class(); ?> data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar" data-offset="10">    
<?php } ?>


  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                                        <div class="container" style="width:940px;">
                                             <ul class="nav">
     <li class="hidden-phone">
         <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL.'weblogo.png'; ?>" style="width:270px;">
     </li>


     <?php if ($detect->isMobile() AND !$detect->isTablet()) {?>
                <li class="dropdown" style="margin-left:15px;">
                <?php }else{ ?>
                     <li class="dropdown offset2">
                <?php } ?>   
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding:0;"><img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>callus.png" style="height:46px;width:203px"></a>
    <?php if ($detect->isMobile() AND !$detect->isTablet()) {                           
              callUsBanner('mobile'); 
            }else{
                callUsBanner('desktop'); 
            }
              ?>
                            </li><!-- Regular Menu Ends -->   



                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>


 </ul>
                                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php if ($detect->isMobile() AND !$detect->isTablet()) {?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile-custom.css" />   
<style>
.hhd{
    display:inline-block;
    height:5px;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
<?php } ?>

  <div class="container hhd" style="height:41px;">
        <?php if ($detect->isMobile() AND !$detect->isTablet()) {?>

                  <img src="weblogo.png" style="width:270px;">
                  <div class="row">
                <div class="styled-select blue semi-square divsel span12">
                     <?php menu1(); ?>
                </div>
                </div>    

                  <?php  }  ?>
<div class="subnavbar navbar navbar hidden-phone">
       <div class="navbar-inner subnav">
         <div class="container">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
             <ul class="nav" style="font-size:13px;">

                  <li class="hidden-phone"><img src="badge.jpg" style="width:40px;"></li> 
                  <li class="hidden-phone"><a href="" style="padding-right: 5px;"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                  <li class="hidden-phone"><a href=""><i class=" icon-th-large"></i>Store</a></li>
                   <li class="hidden-phone"><a href=""><i class=" icon-tag"></i>Bursa</a></li>
                   <li class="divider-vertical subnav"></li>

                <?php  menuIjo('desktop','top');  ?>
             </ul>       

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
<script>
    $('.renav').click(function(e){
        //alert('ha');
        $('section.dropdown-menu *').removeAttr('data-toggle');
    });
 </script>
<!-- End Header -->
          <!-- Begin Template Content -->
```